# What is the equivalent value for appbar_scrolling_view_behavior in the material library of androidx?

Tags: android, androidx, android-nestedscrollview

Recently I migrate to `anroidx`. In the xml layout I use of the `NestedScrollView`. Before I set `@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior` value for the `layout_behavior` attribute. Now this value is undefined in the xml file. What is the equivalent value for this property in the material library?
[image]

Comment: It looks to be still the same: https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/blob/master/lib/java/com/google/android/material/appbar/res-public/values/public.xml#L42. Are you sure you have the correct dependency for Material Components in your `build.gradle`? https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/blob/master/docs/getting-started.md

Comment: Yes I use correct dependency. `implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0'`.

Comment: You might try a newer version. It looks like `appbar_scrolling_view_behavior` wasn't public in the initial release.

Comment: Now I add `implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0-alpha06'`. When I use this string for example in the Textview widget, It is recognized but It seems `layout_behavior` attribute don't accept a string value.

Comment: Um, it should: https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/support/+/androidx-master-dev/coordinatorlayout/src/main/res/values/attrs.xml#36. What's the exact error message you get? Did you try a clean/rebuild?

Comment: I put a image of my xml layout. I also clean and rebuild project.

Comment: What's the exact error message?

Comment: Unresolved class '@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior' less... (Ctrl+F1) 
Inspection info: Validates resource references inside Android XML files.

Comment: Try Invalidate Caches/Restart.

Comment: My Project run correctly. Only xml layout not recognize this string.

Comment: Yeah, it's recognizing the string. It just thinks it can't find the referenced class, but it's gotta be there, obviously. Sounds like just an IDE hiccup. Try the Invalidate Caches/Restart.

Comment: I try Invalidate Caches/Restart.But problem still didn't solve.

Comment: Looks to be an ongoing issue: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/131403371. I'm sure they'll fix it eventually, maybe.

Comment: I hope. thank a lot